# Producing plot for a group of line in a loop to easily create different plot from a file containing a lot of data?

Tags: python, csv, plot

first time posting (and being on this site) and I'm quite new at python so sometimes I make stupids mistakes.

So I have a csv file with many many line presented like this:

```
scode;sname;Date;lon;lat;obs-is;obs-sat
RK74877245MP8551;Prop;43167;-9.70152;52.4864;0.500000;
RK74877245MP8551;Prop;43998;-9.70152;52.4864;9.60000;
RK74877245MP8551;Prop;44055;-9.70152;52.4864;3.60000;
RK74877248PY3001;Ray;42536;-9.15470;53.2328;2.40000;
RK74877248PY3001;Ray;42576;-9.15470;53.2328;1.50000;
RK74877248PY3001;Ray;42619;-9.15470;53.2328;1.80000;
RK74877248PY3001;Ray;43299;-9.15470;53.2328;1.20000;
RK74877248PY3001;Ray;43333;-9.15470;53.2328;1.70000;
RK74877248PY3001;Ray;-9.15470;53.2328;0.500000;
RK74877248PR8502;Dlop;42536;-9.21554;53.2395;1.50000;
RK74877248PR8502;Dlop;-9.21554;53.2395;1.50000;
RK74877248PR8502;Dlop;-9.21554;53.2395;1.10000;
RK74877248PR8502;Dlop;-9.21554;53.2395;0.500000;
RK74877248PR8502;Dlop;-9.21554;53.2395;1.50000;
RK74877248PR8502;Dlop;-9.21554;53.2395;1.50000;
RK74878954RK3065;Blu;42956;-9.26645;53.2228;0.500000;
```

Basically each line represent a location with the code of the station, the name of the place, latitudes,longitudes, and the observations in the last two columns. This one is only a part but the original file has more than 2000 lines. There is multiple lines for a same location. There is no obs-sat in this extract but there is in the original file.

What I'm trying to do is make a scatter plot for each different location with the different value of obs-is and obs-sat on the same plot with the date as the x axis (btw I know my date are weird, it's normal). For example, the first one would be 3 point on a plot for obs-is for the 3 dates indicated, but no point obs-sat since there wasn't any observations of this type.

To do so I tried to do different thing, mainly by using the "scode" to create a loop. Like for each scode create a plot with only the data of the group of lines concerned by this scode. I tried to create a dictionnary of tuple but it complicated thing more than necessary. I tried different loops "while","for" and "if" without success. I also tried to use the header name but it doesn't seems to work either.

The following code is one example of many that doesn't work or when it work it just make a plot of the totality of the file.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("E:/IRLANDE/IRISH_SAT_IS_PLOT_2.csv", sep=";")


code=df.iloc[:,0]
x=df.iloc[:,2]
y1=df.iloc[:,5]
y2=df.iloc[:,6]

C=code.tolist()
Cint=C[:1]
l2=l[:1]
print(Cint)
print(l2)

if Cint==l2:
    plt.figure() 
    plt.xlabel('Dates')
    plt.ylabel('niveau obs')
    plt.plot(x, y1, 'o', color='black')
    plt.plot(x, y2, 'o', color='orange')
    plt.savefig('testplot.png')
    plt.show()
```

I searched a lot on the internet but doesn't seem to be able to find any answer about how to do this correctly and in a pythonic way. All the answer are always on other specific problem that I doesn't seem to be able to integrate into my code.
So is there anybody here who has an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So after a good night sleep and a little more research I finally came up with a solution.
A very simple solution I think but like I said, I'm a newbie and make simple mistakes.

So my solution is to not define x and y outside the loop as to keep only the values corresponding to my demand.

And I got the expected result with a code as follow:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df=pd.read_csv("E:/IRLANDE/IRISH_SAT_IS_PLOT_2.csv", sep=";")

for code in df2['scode']:
    plt.figure()
    plt.title('Station '+code)
    x=df2.loc[df2['scode'] == code, 'date']
    y1=df2.loc[df2['scode'] == code, 'obs-is']
    y2=df2.loc[df2['scode'] == code, 'obs-sat']
    plt.xlabel('Dates')
    plt.ylabel('Chlorophylle-a (µg/L)')
    plt.plot(x, y1, 'o', color='black', label='in-situ')
    plt.plot(x, y2, 'o', color='orange', label='satellite')
    plt.legend(title='Données',bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.savefig(code +'_log10.png', bbox_inches="tight")
```

Basically the important part was to use `x=df2.loc[df2['scode'] == code, 'date']`
to define x or y instead of trying to attribute the column value first and then determine which row was the corresponding one in the loop. Here the loop determine automatically which value have to be represented.